# Txt list divide columns

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a bunch of data stored in a single column in a txt file, something like this:

```
name1
address1
number1
name2
address2
number2
name3
address3
number3
name4
address4
number4
```

etc

I want to sort this in 3 columns so it can be imported to excel.

Any clues?

Comment: Please provide us with the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `Microsoft word`!

Paste the data into MSWord (as `keep text only`), then select them all (`Ctrl+A`). go to `insert` ribbon. From `Table` button, select `convert text to table`.

Choose the `number of columns` 3 and select `separate text at` as `Paragraph`.

It will give you the exact output you want. No need to code everything you encounter. You can read more about it [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/convert-text-to-a-table-or-a-table-to-text-in-word-for-mac-cca876cd-fef8-4edc-b66a-afd3193ac279).

Comment: Great! Couldn't have been solved in an easier way! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You might want something like this:

```
with open("input.txt", "r") as infile:

  line = infile.read().split()
  line = [" ".join(line[i:i+3]) for i in range(0,len(line),3)]
  print(line)

  with open("output.txt", "w") as outfile:
    for i in line:
      outfile.write(i + "\n")
```

Contents of `output.txt`:

```
name1 address1 number1
name2 address2 number2
name3 address3 number3
name4 address4 number4
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
infile = open("data.txt","r")

outfile = open("Excel.csv","w")

while True:
    name = infile.readline().strip()
    address = infile.readline().strip()
    number = infile.readline().strip()

    data = ','.join([name,address,number])
    if data == ",,":
        break

    data += '\n'
    outfile.write(data)
```

If I remember from my Excel days, it does very well with CSV's.

Comment: Don't forget to call `infile.close()` and `outfile.close()` after you finish your task.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this uses a piece of code that has needlessly been re-written thousands of times because for some reason it is not yet included in the standard library (or as a built-in of some kind, which could make life even easier) despite a recurring necessity for it's use in python. A version is included in Vasilis G.'s answer.

```
chunk_by_length(iterable, length):
    return (iterable[i:i+length] for i in range(0, len(iterable), length))
```

Once you have this simple but extremely handy function at your disposal, this problem is trivial.

```
data = open('data.txt').read().splitlines()
formatted = '\n'.join(','.join(chunk) for chunk in chunk_by_length(data, 3))
open('data.csv', 'w').write(formatted)
```

Although an accepted answer has already been selected, I am still posting this to help anyone attempting to solve this or similar problems in python.